# Move authentication to customer-email in checkout page Magento 2

Tags: authentication, magento, magento2, checkout

I want to move authentication to customer-email in checkout page Magento 2 like picture below. But I can't, it's not working

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LplKb.png)

Here is my code in file checkout_index_index.xml:

```
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="customer-email" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress</item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!--Additional authentication fields-->
                                                                        <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication-messages</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.